# Can I Keep an Order to Items in a Junction Table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get a better understanding of junction tables and table joins. If I have two tables, ***loops*** and ***stops***, that have a many-to-many relationship, how can I display the **stops** in their ***respective*** order?

Currently, I have two flat tables that look like this.

### Loops Table

```
+----+-------+ 
| id | loops |
+----+-------+
|  1 | Red   |
|  2 | Green |
|  3 | Blue  |
+----+-------+
```

### Stops Table (unsorted)

```
+---------------------+-------+--------------+----+
|        stops        | loops | displayOrder | id |
+---------------------+-------+--------------+----+
| West Stop           | Red   |            1 | 12 |
| North Stop          | Red   |            2 | 43 |
| Building Stop       | Red   |            3 | 15 |
| Park Stop           | Red   |            4 | 14 |
| Park Stop           | Green |            1 | 42 |
| West Stop           | Green |            3 | 11 |
| Building Stop       | Green |            2 |  8 |
| Building Stop       | Blue  |            1 |  2 |
| Park Stop           | Blue  |            3 |  4 |
| West Stop           | Blue  |            2 |  6 |
+---------------------+-------+--------------+----+
```

If I were to filter the ***stops*** column in the ***stops*** table, you can see that there are stops that have multiple loops since different bus loops can visit these stops. You can see that the ordering is different for each ***loop*** as well.

```
+----------+-------+--------------+----+
|  stops   | loops | displayOrder | id |
+----------+-------+--------------+----+
| WestStop | Red   |            1 | 12 |
| WestStop | Green |            3 | 11 |
| WestStop | Blue  |            2 | 6  |
+----------+-------+--------------+----+
```

Is there a way I can use a junction table and table join to get only ***stops*** for a specific ***loop*** while maintaining its order?

[This Article](https://megocode3.wordpress.com/2008/01/04/understanding-a-sql-junction-table/) talks about how to create a junction table but I'm still unsure how I can maintain a display order without having an ugly, flat database with multiple stops for multiple loops like I have now.

I'm also aware that I should probably be using the ***loops in the Stops table*** values as a foreign key to the ***loops in the Loops table***

Comment: update your question and add the expected  result  . too

Comment: 3 tables.. Loop, Stop, and loop_stop.  you can have a column in loop_stop to tell the order of the stops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 3 tables.

Loop, Stop and one table to join them ROUTE.

[image]

You can also imagine a table to link stops to other stops that tells you the distance between them and the time it takes. then you would theoretically use that type of info to determine optimal routes.

Comment: that won't help with the order unless there is an ordering column

Answer (score 1):

You have a many to many relationship between bus lines (loops) and bus stops : using a junction table is the standard way to go.

In the junction table, says loops_stops, you want to store a fk to the bus lines, another fk to the bus stops, and the sequence of the stop of the line. You can have a unique key on the two constraint columns (include the sequence of it is possible that the same stop is served twice by the same line). Nb : un MySQL, you usually want to use autoincremented integer primary keys.

In the stops table, you store information that is common to stops, like the name, location, equipments and so on.

Using a junction table is the proper way to represent your data. It will also prevent you from duplicating information in the lines tables. We can see that this is starting to happen with your sample data : what if you need to add an information that is common to all lines ? in your sample data (eg location) ? You would need to duplicate it on each row, which is not efficient and a maintenance nightmare when you need to update that value.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the data in the table is not guaranteed unless specified.

You need to either

- Add an ordering column
- Sort by loop, displayorder or id
- Create a junction table and add an ordering column to your junction table.

So for example

```
Loop_ID Stop_ID Order
1         12      1
1         43      2
1         15      3
1         14      4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without junction table as below:

```
Declare @Loop Table
(Loop_Id int,
Name varchar(50))

Insert into @Loop
Values
(1,'Red'),
(2,'Green'),
(3,'Blue')

Declare @Stop_Table Table
(Stops varchar(500),
Loops varchar(50),
DisplayOrder int,
Id int)

Insert into @Stop_Table
(Stops,Loops,DisplayOrder,Id)
Values
('West Stop'        ,'Red'              ,'1','12'),
 ('North Stop'       ,'Red'              ,'2','43'),
 ('Building Stop'    ,'Red'              ,'3','15'),
 ('Park Stop'        ,'Red'              ,'4','14'),
 ('Park Stop'        ,'Green'            ,'1','42'),
 ('West Stop'        ,'Green'            ,'3','11'),
 ('Building Stop'    ,'Green'            ,'2','8'),
 ('Building Stop'    ,'Blue'             ,'1','2'),
 ('Park Stop'        ,'Blue'             ,'3','4'),
 ('West Stop'        ,'Blue'             ,'2','6')

 --To get all loops sort
 select S.*,L.* from @Stop_Table S
 Join @Loop L
 On L.Name = S.Loops
 Order by L.Loop_Id,S.DisplayOrder asc

--To get stops for a specific loop.For Ex:Red
 select S.*,L.* from @Stop_Table S
 Join @Loop L
 On L.Name = S.Loops
 where L.Name = 'Red'
 Order by L.Loop_Id,S.DisplayOrder asc
```